# Does the Mid-Point Between the Forces Move Up Or Down?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

I've drawn an image of a thin rod with a mass at the end of it. The centre of mass is the red dot and I've drawn 2 forces applied at one end of the rod as shown.

I understand there will be a net force 10N up and therefore expect the COM to move up. But can anyone advise whether the mid-point between the 2 forces (yellow dot) will also go up or go down from its original position?

[image]

Comment: I don't know why are you facing problem with this. You considered here that the net force is 10N upwards. So, every point of the rod will go upwards.

Comment: It's not as simple as that as you can see from Petrini's answer below. Check out Chasles theorem (kinematics).

Answer (score 0):

For a rigid body you can always transform a force system into a single force applied directly at the CoM and a pure torque ("force couple" in some engineering texts). In your case, the sum of forces is $10$ N upwards, but the sum of torques about the CoM (red) is $10$ N.m counterclock-wise (verify).

Using [some formulae](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En4/notes_old/RigidKinematics/rigkin.htm#:%7E:text=All%20lines%20on%20a%20rigid%20body%20have%20the%20same%20angular,a%20rotation%20about%20the%20point.) for rigid body motion in arbitrary frames, you get:
$$
\mathbf{a}_{\text{yellow}} = \mathbf{a}_{\text{red}} + \mathbf{\alpha} \times \mathbf{r}_{\text{yellow relative to red}}
$$

Where:
$$
I \mathbf{\alpha} = \mathbf{\tau} \Longrightarrow \mathbf{\alpha} = \frac{1}{I}\mathbf{\tau} = \frac{10 \text{N.m}}{I}\mathbf{\hat{k}}
$$
$$
\mathbf{r}_{\text{yellow relative to red}} = - 0.9\text{m}\mathbf{\hat{i}}
$$
And by Newton's second law:
$$
\mathbf{a}_{\text{red}} = \frac{10 N}{M}\mathbf{\hat{j}}
$$
(take $\mathbf{\hat{i}}$ to the right, $\mathbf{\hat{j}}$ up and $\mathbf{\hat{k}}$ out of the screen, pointing at you).

Replacing:
$$
\mathbf{a}_{\text{yellow}} = \frac{10 N}{M}\mathbf{\hat{j}} - \frac{9 \text{N.m}^2}{I}\mathbf{\hat{k}} \times \mathbf{\hat{i}} = \left[ \frac{10}{M} - \frac{9}{I}\right]\mathbf{\hat{j}}
$$
so if it all starts at rest, it will actually start going up or down depending on which term above dominates...
You can fill the remaining details with $M = 0.3 kg$ and by calculating $I$ for slender bar using [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) and a [table of moments of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia)...

Comment: Many thanks for this Petrini.